# Upload Image and String Using MultipartAPI

Tags: objective-c, image, file-upload

i want to upload the image and string using multipartform data
Here is my code,

```
 +(void)UploadImageWithAlldetails:(NSDictionary *)string imageresource:(NSData *)imageResource andCompletion:(GFWebServiceHandler)completion
 {
 NSString *createNoteUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",BASE_URL,API_TO_UPLOAD_IMAGE];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: string
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:nil];
NSString *jsonString =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:createNoteUrl]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];


NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";
//set conteent type in HTTP header

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;boundary=%@",boundary];
//[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content_Type"];

NSMutableData *body =[NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition : form-data; name = %@\r\n\r\n",@"userDetails"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type :application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n",jsonString]
            dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//image data

if (imageResource) {


    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=imageName.png\r\n", @"userImage"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageResource]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n",boundary ] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setHTTPBody:body];



  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
        //success
        NSLog(@"%@",response);

        NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@",stringFromData);


    }
}];

}
```

i have implemented the above code, i am getting json data from server and i have nslog that ,it shows like,res-type :error,msg:error occured while uploading .

Please anyone help me ,to do this ,
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: image name is in imageName.png and image is in JPEG formate

Answer (score 0):

use **AFNetWorking** to upload a image

here is how i do ,hope this will help :)

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@mvs-itsm/%@",itsmUrl,@"attUpload"];
[params setObject:attchementID forKey:@"id"];
[params setObject:attType forKey:@"type"];

AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializerReq = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
serializerReq.timeoutInterval = 60.f;
[serializerReq setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serializerReq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [MVSUserDefaults getToken]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
//    [serializerReq setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Encoding"];
//    [serializerReq setValue:@"gzip, deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
NSError *error;

NSMutableURLRequest *requset = [serializerReq multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataToUpload name:@"file" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",UUID(),@"jpg"] mimeType:type];
} error:&error];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
AFHTTPResponseSerializer *serializerRes = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = serializerRes;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *datatask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:requset progress:progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    //do your own work
}];
[datatask resume];
```

Comment: Thanks yu xiao,I want to send image and nsstring ,what should i want to add for sending image and string

Comment: you may notice there is a **parmas** parameter in sentence

Comment: you may notice there is a parmas parameter in sentence `NSMutableURLRequest *requset = [serializerReq multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataToUpload name:@"file" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",UUID(),@"jpg"] mimeType:type];
} error:&error];`

Comment: so edit **parmas** like `NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];  [params setObject:name forKey:filed]; ` so you can add you own string

Comment: @ yu xiao,i am getting error like,implicit declaration of function UUID is invalid c99,Please help me to do this

Comment: oh,you can just use a random UUID string to replace it